# unable to run `make` and `make install` when trying to install ideviceactivate

Tags: make

I'm unable to install `ideviceactivate` on my Ubuntu 16.4. I got the clone directory [from github](https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate). When I run `make` I get this:

```
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate-master/src'
gcc -o ideviceactivate ideviceactivate.c activate.c cache.c util.c -g -pthread -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -limobiledevice -lplist -lusbmuxd -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lgnutls -ltasn1 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl
activate.c: In function ‘do_activation’:
activate.c:325:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘plist_to_xml’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  plist_to_xml(activation_record, &xml, &len);
                                  ^
In file included from activate.c:26:0:
/usr/include/plist/plist.h:576:10: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
     void plist_to_xml(plist_t plist, char **plist_xml, uint32_t * length);
          ^
activate.c:326:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("ACTIVATION RECORD:\n\n%s\n\n", xml);
         ^
cache.c: In function ‘cache_plist’:
cache.c:104:23: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘plist_to_xml’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   plist_to_xml(plist, &xml, &len);
                       ^
In file included from cache.c:21:0:
/usr/include/plist/plist.h:576:10: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
     void plist_to_xml(plist_t plist, char **plist_xml, uint32_t * length);
          ^
cache.c: In function ‘get_from_cache’:
cache.c:120:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘read_file’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  read_file((const char *)fname, &d);
                                 ^
cache.c:48:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[2097152]’
 int read_file(const char *filename, char data[BUFSIZE])
     ^
cache.c:122:9: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  return (char *)d;
         ^
util.c: In function ‘buffer_read_from_filename’:
util.c:48:10: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Unable to read %llu bytes from '%s'.\n", size, filename);
          ^
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate-master/src'
dyrexion@dyrexion-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads/ideviceactivate-master$ sudo make
[sudo] password for dyrexion: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for dyrexion: 
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate-master/src'
gcc -o ideviceactivate ideviceactivate.c activate.c cache.c util.c -g -pthread -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -limobiledevice -lplist -lusbmuxd -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lgnutls -ltasn1 -lxml2 -lglib-2.0 -lcurl
activate.c: In function ‘do_activation’:
activate.c:325:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘plist_to_xml’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  plist_to_xml(activation_record, &xml, &len);
                                  ^
In file included from activate.c:26:0:
/usr/include/plist/plist.h:576:10: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
     void plist_to_xml(plist_t plist, char **plist_xml, uint32_t * length);
          ^
activate.c:326:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("ACTIVATION RECORD:\n\n%s\n\n", xml);
         ^
cache.c: In function ‘cache_plist’:
cache.c:104:23: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘plist_to_xml’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   plist_to_xml(plist, &xml, &len);
                       ^
In file included from cache.c:21:0:
/usr/include/plist/plist.h:576:10: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’
     void plist_to_xml(plist_t plist, char **plist_xml, uint32_t * length);
          ^
cache.c: In function ‘get_from_cache’:
cache.c:120:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘read_file’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  read_file((const char *)fname, &d);
                                 ^
cache.c:48:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char * (*)[2097152]’
 int read_file(const char *filename, char data[BUFSIZE])
     ^
cache.c:122:9: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  return (char *)d;
         ^
util.c: In function ‘buffer_read_from_filename’:
util.c:48:10: warning: format ‘%llu’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("Unable to read %llu bytes from '%s'.\n", size, filename);
          ^
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate-master/src'
```

and I can`t proceed to`make install`if`make` wasn't done successfully.  What could have gone wrong in this?

Comment: From where you downloaded source code of this program?

Comment: (https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate)  straight from github

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any issues on clean 16.04 LTS.

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libplist-dev \
libimobiledevice-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/posixninja/ideviceactivate.git
cd ideviceactivate
make
sudo make install
```

Then it starts normally:

```
$ ideviceactivate
No device found, is it plugged in?
```

Comment: after cloning, what to do in order to run `make`? because i can`t just run it anywhere. it would say "no target specified"

Comment: I'm sorry, forget to add `cd ideviceactivate`. Now fixed.

Comment: ok. i still got the same problem. i don't really know why. and when i run `make install` it just doesn't respond {dyrexion@dyrexion-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads/ideviceactivate$ sudo su
root@dyrexion-Aspire-E1-531:/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate# make install
cp src/ideviceactivate /usr/local/bin/ideviceactivate
root@dyrexion-Aspire-E1-531:/home/dyrexion/Downloads/ideviceactivate# 
}

Comment: I can't understand about "doesn't respond". I have recorded [screencast](https://asciinema.org/a/OZi9OAnP3d2d5J7wMSh1zOJXS). Do you have any differences in terminal behavior?

Comment: thank you. i guess it is the same results i get. the problem with it is that when i run a command `ideviceactivate` with my device connected, i get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`  should i post this one as a separate issue?

Comment: As we finished installation part you can [accept my answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). Yes, I think it is other issue. You can open it as another question. Also please note that program from 2010 may not work with devices from 2018.